# Read Google spreadsheet using Python and compare values with text file

Tags: python

I have a Google spreadsheet with a list of domains, I also have a list of domains in a text file. I want to open the spreadsheet using the Google API for Python, and check if the a domain exists in the text file if it does, set a flag value of 1 in a cell if not set a value of 0.

So far I have this code:

```
feed = gdataclient.GetListFeed(spreadsheet_key,
                                       worksheet_id)
row = 2
  #column index=12 corresponds to column name 'validdomain'
  col = 11
  domains = [domain.strip() for domain in open(domains_file,'r')]
  for row_entry in feed.entry:
    record = text_db.Record(row_entry=row_entry)
    if record.content['domainname'] in domains:
      gdataclient.UpdateCell(row = row,
                                 col = col,
                                 inputValue = '1' ,
                                 key = spreadsheet_key,
                                 wksht_id = worksheet_id)
    else:
      gdataclient.UpdateCell(row = row,
                                 col = col,
                                 inputValue = '0' ,
                                 key = spreadsheet_key,
                                 wksht_id = worksheet_id)
    row += 1
```

Because the spreadsheet is large this code keeps timing out.

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355743/python-control-timeout-length it deals with timeout of web service calls in python, might be helpful

Comment: My best bet is to use Batch Update but i'm not sure how to go about it